# Google Cloud Platform - Java API Client Library - Cloud Run - Add IAM Policy Binding for a service

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-cloud-run, google-api-java-client

I have researched enough and I am getting nowhere. Hoping I can get some help here.

In GCP, How can I add a new IAM policy binding for a Cloud run service using Java API client library SDK?

Simply put, I need the equivalent of this gcloud command in the JAVA SDK.

`gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding hello-fully-managed --member=allUsers --role=roles/run.invoker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have this equivalent in the SDK and you need to call the API by yourselves.

In addition in the API, the ADD doesn't exist, only [the set and the get](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.services). Therefore, you need to

- Get the existing policy
- Add the policy binding that you wish (account + role)
- Set the whole updated policy

You can get inspiration from the API Calls performed by the gcloud command by using the `--log-http` parameter to view the in and out of the API.

Comment: I came across cloudResourceManager.projects().setIamPolicy method. However, it seems to work only for projects. I was wondering if there is something at services level. Am I right in understanding that there is support at project level policy binding in the JAVA SDK but not at service level?

Comment: Yes, there isn't SDK (java and other languages) for Cloud Run and thus you need to use the APIs directly at service level.